# linear regression F test on equality of two variables result contradicts t test on each one what is the meaning of this?

Tags: regression

I have done f test to check if B1=B2 in my linear regression I got f static more than pv so we failed to reject the null hypothesis indicating they maybe equal. however when t test is done to check the significance of each one alone B1 was significant and B2 was insignificant. what is the meaning of this? how come one significant variable is equal to insignificant one?

Comment: "The difference between significant and insignificant is not significant". That is the title of a paper that appeared in the journal The American Statistician, and it applies here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two tests you performed are of different hypotheses, therefore, they can generate different results without contradicting each other.

The $F$ test tests for $\beta_1 = \beta_2$.

The two $t$ tests test for $\beta_1 = 0$ and $\beta_2 = 0$.  Consider a situation where the estimates of $\beta_1 = 1.8$ and $\beta_2 = 2.2$, and the standard error of each equals $1$.  Your $t$ tests will fail to reject the null hypothesis of $\beta_1 = 0$ at the 95% level of confidence, but will reject the null hypothesis of $\beta_2 = 0$.   However, $\hat{\beta_1}$ and $\hat{\beta_2}$ are not all that different from each other, and with standard errors of $1$, it's not at all surprising that we would be unable to conclude that the difference of $0.4$ between them was significant.  Indeed, they might well both be equal to, say, $2$ - which is definitely not equal to $0$.

This is a phenomenon that Andrew Gelman and Hal Stern have referred to as "The difference between "significant" and "not significant" is not itself statistically significant."  [Signficance paper](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/research/published/signif4.pdf)